# How to publish multiple messages in google Pub/Sub fast?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

How to publish multiple messages to pubsub fast? Without multiprocessing and multithreading becaue the code is already in a Thread

The code bellow is publishing 40 messages per second

```
publisher = pubsub.PublisherClient(
    credentials=credentials,
    batch_settings=types.BatchSettings(
         max_messages=1000,  # default is 100
        max_bytes=1 * 1000 * 1000,  # 1 MiB
        max_latency=0.1,  # default is 10 ms
    )
)

topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    topic=TOPIC_PUBSUB,
)

for data in results:
    bytes_json_data = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
    future = publisher.publish(topic_name, bytes_json_data)
    future.result()
```

Comment: 40 messages per second isn't so fast. And you batching configuration should be enough. What's your issue?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of publishing the messages one at a time and then wait on the `future`, you should publish them all at once and then wait on the published `futures` at the end. It will look something like:

```
from concurrent import futures
...
publish_futures = []
for data in results:
    bytes_json_data = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
    future = publisher.publish(topic_name, bytes_json_data)
    publish_futures.append(future)
...
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
```

There's a [detailed example in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher?hl=en#batching) with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Take out:

```
future.result()
```

Leave it just:

```
for data in results:
    bytes_json_data = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
    future = publisher.publish(topic_name, bytes_json_data)
```

And should take it less than a second to publish 10k messages